# Handle Weekly Data in MySQL with Multiple User IDs and Columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a cron that will run every week and grab data from an API and store this data in a database. I'd like to keep different data in separate columns, but be able to view each set of data grouped into week #x or something. What would be the best way to store this data so I can view weekly data (multiple columns of values grouped by week) in this database which each row being a different user with a unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

What you need just add a special column for Monday's date,then can get weekly data by it's monday.

```
ID
your data
monday (YYYYMMDD or Timestamp)
create_date
update_date
```